# Change value in a dropdownlist from standard value to a specific country if a specific user has a country

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

So I got this problem (ofcourse) where a user choose a country when they edit their profilepage and when they choose a country I want my other dropdownlist to show that value.

Here is my example:

```
 if (UserhasCountry)
                {

  var user = startPage.SelectedCountry == currentUser.GetAttributeValue<string>("Country");


                }
```

Explain: Startpage.selectedcountry is the dropdownlist i want to fill out with the specific country from the user. But when i debug this I get that selectedcountry still is Global. I want the specific country like Sweden or something,

Comment: i didn't get what you say. show the value of selected country or fill value on basis of selection? Please share your code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the value of the drop down list instead of the text, i.e. if you wanna set the country selected in the drop down list, get the id of the country set by the user and use that id to set the selected value of drop down list.

eg: startPage.SelectedCountry.selectedvalue = "1";

Thank you.